# Avoid duplicate row to SUM twice

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, duplicates

I have a table with duplicate rows, how can I sum that duplicate row as distinct value? I am aware I can insert distinct data into a new table and sum it that way but I am trying to avoid creating any sort of table.
Table:

```
SELECT '123' DateID,'8' HOUR,'6000' AMT, '20150801' PayEndingDate, '20150807' CheckDate
INTO #DATA
UNION ALL
SELECT '456',8,'6000','20150801','20150807' UNION ALL
SELECT '789',8,'6000','20150801','20150807' UNION ALL --DUP ROW
SELECT '789',8,'6000','20150801','20150807' UNION ALL --DUP ROW
SELECT '987',8,'6000','20150725','20150807' UNION ALL
SELECT '654',8,'6000','20150725','20150807' UNION ALL
SELECT '321',8,'6000','20150725','20150807' UNION ALL --DUP ROW
SELECT '321',8,'6000','20150725','20150807' --DUP ROW
SELECT * FROM #DATA

|DateID | HOUR  | AMT      | PayEndingDate  | CheckDate
 123      8       6000       20150801         20150807
 456      8       6000       20150801         20150807
 789      8       6000       20150801         20150807
 789      8       6000       20150801         20150807
 987      8       6000       20150725         20150807
 654      8       6000       20150725         20150807
 321      8       6000       20150725         20150807
 321      8       6000       20150725         20150807

SELECT  DISTINCT SUM(HOUR) AS HOURS, AMT, PayEndingDate, CHECKDATE
FROM #DATA
GROUP BY AMT,PayEndingDate,CHECKDATE

| HOUR  | AMT      | PayEndingDate  | CheckDate
  32      6000       20150725         20150807
  32      6000       20150801         20150807
```

As you can see ID `321` and `789` are duplicated and causing hours to be 32 instead it should be 24. Adding distinct inside SUM returns just 8. How can I avoid dups in this scenario?

Comment: Why aren't you summing the `AMT`?

Comment: No need for `SELECT DISTINCT` since the `GROUP BY` returns no duplicate rows.

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
Select SUM(HOUR) AS HOURS, AMT, PayEndingDate, CHECKDATE
From (
SELECT  DISTINCT DateID, HOUR , AMT, PayEndingDate, CHECKDATE
FROM #DATA
) A
GROUP BY AMT,PayEndingDate,CHECKDATE
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to avoid inner query as well. I am guessing there isn't any other way but this or temp table or CTE. It has to be referenced from something else (inner query, cte, temp table)

Comment: You need to weed out the duplicates prior to summing up the data. This is the easiest way to do so without making it more complex code.

Answer (score 2):

DISTINCT can be a little expensive on it's own. Personally, I prefer using A CTE and ROW_NUMBER:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DateID ORDER BY DateID) AS RN
    FROM #Data)
SELECT SUM(HOUR) AS HOURS, AMT, PayEndingDate, CHECKDATE
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
GROUP BY AMT, PayEndingDate, CHECKDATE;
```

Comment: No, not unless used incorrectly. I's an expression, like a CASE. Where did you get that idea that it was?